# Display google calendar for different timezones

Tags: javascript, iframe, calendar, timezone, google-calendar-api

For my website, I will have users from different timezones and I want to display my google calendar according to their particular timezone. Right now, I have an iframe with the source as my google calendar and it looks like this:

```html
<iframe id="ll-calendar-iframe" src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=03d500sqj7smu2ho2on9set69k%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FToronto&amp;color=%231aa3ff&amp;bgcolor=%23f9cf00&amp;showTz=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;mode=WEEK" style="border:solid 2px #182C57; border-radius: 7px;" width="1200" height="700" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

One way that I think I can achieve this is by obtaining the user's timezone and then use javascript to change the source of the calendar by changing the part where the timezone is specified - `ctz=America%2FToronto`.

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it or there are better ways of displaying the calendar for different timezones. Is there something offered by Google Calendar API that would help me to accomplish this?

Comment: You can retrieve the user's timezone via [Settings: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings/get), and then change the value of `ctz` accordingly. Do you think that would be an appropriate solution for you?